# Elastic Stack not booting with GNU Parallel

Tags: elasticsearch, virtual-machine, elastic-stack, gnu-parallel, elastic-enterprise-search

I am trying to run a stack of Elasticsearch, Kibana, and enterprise-search on an ubuntu VM (8gb ram, 4 CPUs). When I run each program individually they boot up fine and I can use each service with no problem, however my problem comes when I try to boot all services with one command using GNU parallel. When running the following command, both Elasticsearch and Kibana boot up fine (with the same logs as if booted separately), but enterprise-search gets stuck on "Enterprise Search is starting.." and is never resolved.

```
parallel --delay 60 --tag -j 3 --halt now,fail=1 --line-buffer ::: './path/to/elasticsearch' './path/to/kibana' './path/to/enterprise-search'
```

I am assuming that I am misunderstanding something with GNU parallel, if there is any clarity that can be shed it would be much appreciated. I am also open to any alternatives I can use to perform a staggered start-up from a single command. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `enterprise-search` require a terminal?

If so add `--tty`:

```
parallel --tty --delay 60 --tag -j 3 --halt now,fail=1 --line-buffer ::: './path/to/elasticsearch' './path/to/kibana' './path/to/enterprise-search'
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry this is so late, but I did get a chance to try your solution and while it didnt quite work, it lead me in the right direction. The working flag was --tmux.